# Identify common subdirectory names between two different directories and delete them

Tags: directory, diff

I have two dirs `dir1` and `dir2` that have hundreds of subdirectories at `depth 1`. I only need information of the subdirectory names that are common between `dir1` and `dir2` and systematically delete them from `dir2`. I don't need to compare files or content of files. Performing

```
diff -qr dir_one dir_two | sort
```

produces the filenames as well, which I'm not interested at the moment.

Comment: Performing the above command without recursion enable the identification of only unique directories. But I'm still not sure how to identify  the common directories and delete them from `dir2`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your use case you can avoid to *identify* the common directories because `rm -rf` just ignores non-existing ones.

So it's enough to `find` *all* directories in `dir1` and delete them from  `dir2`:

```
find dir1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "dir2/%f\0" |xargs -0 rm -rf --
```

Some explanations. By default `find` would print all the dirs with full path which is `dir1`. So we are using `-printf` to print only the file name without leading directories (%f) plus the other path "dir2" where we want to delete. Furthermore we terminate the string with null byte '\0' rather than newline to use `xarg` option `-0` which makes all this safe regarding filenames with spaces. Then `xargs` will read stdin and execute the `rm` command by adding all strings as arguments.

Note before actually deleting them you may test your command line by adding `echo` to only print the `rm` commands:

```
find dir1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "dir2/%f\0" |xargs -0 echo rm -rf --
```

To only *list* the common directories you could use `ls` instead of `rm` (adding 2>/dev/null to ignore non-existing ones):

```
find dir1 -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf "dir2/%f\0" |xargs -0 -r ls -d -- 2>/dev/null
```

Comment: This seems to work. Thank you. A little more explanation on how the printf and xargs part of the command works, I can accept your answer.

Comment: Can you help me to extend this (i) to do it recursively at multiple depths (ii) delete the subdirectories that are NOT common.

Answer (score 1):

```
comm -1 -3 <( cd dir1 && find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort ) <( cd dir2 && find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort ) | ( cd dir2 && xargs rm -rf )
```

with line breaks for readability:

```
comm -1 -3 <( cd dir1 && find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort ) \
           <( cd dir2 && find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort ) \
                | ( cd dir2 && xargs rm -rf )
```

explanation

```
find -maxdepth 1 -type d
```

list only directories without subdirectories.

```
cd dir1 && find -maxdepth 1 -type d | sort
```

first change to directory then list directories.

```
<( ... )
```

[process substitution](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst).

```
comm -1 -3 <( ... ) <( ... )
```

take first input and second input and print lines unique to second input. in effect this will print directories which are in `dir2` but not in `dir1`.

```
... | ( cd dir2 && xargs rm -rf )
```

change working directory to `dir2` then execute `rm -rf` with output of previous command as arguments. in effect this will delete the directories which are in `dir2` but not in `dir1`.

test first by removing the pipe to `xargs` and inspecting the output.

Answer (score -1):

```
find dir1 dir2 -maxdepth 2 | egrep '/' | xargs --max-args 1 basename | sort | uniq -c  | egrep -v '^      1 ' | while read n de ; do echo rm -rfv dir2/$de ; done
```

remove the echo when correct.